Cant get Windows fully working iMac 10,1 (Black screen, display corrupted)
I have an iMac 10,1 (Late 2009, 21.5 Inch, Core 2 Duo E7600, ATI Radeon HD 4670) and I've been desperately trying to install fully working Windows 10 for the last 3 days without success.
The main issue at hand is that after following the process of BCA, the system reboots to install Windows and my internal screen goes completely black while my external monitor works fine. Even after completing Windows installation, updating etc. I cannot for the life of me get the internal screen working.
Things I've tried to resolve the issue:

Reset SMC
Reset PRAM
Uninstall drivers in Safe Mode
Re-installed different versions of the drivers (ones that BCA
downloaded, ones directly downloaded from AMD support website for
Win8/10, updated ones from Apple supposedly fixing the black screen
issue).
Booted from CD and using CMD and deleted atikmdag.sys
Erased/Re-installed Windows multiple times
Tried Windows 7,10,11 both in 32-64 bit.

Windows has installed using Legacy Mode. If I install using UEFI mode then my internal screen and external monitor do work but the internal monitor is divided into 2 small parts mirroring each other, with horizontal black lines which cause a burn in and several artefacts.
The only way I have managed to get the internal screen working is by installing in UEFI mode. However this uses the Basic Display Adapter. When I try to update using my GPU's drivers, the external monitor works but it corrupts my internal screen. Here's a picture www.ibb.co/HFn5G0R.
The thing is that the internal screen ONLY works with a UEFI installation. Otherwise as soon as I boot either into a legacy setup or legacy installed disk my internal screen goes completely black, no backlight whatsoever. It's like it's disabled, not even recognized in settings. Windows only detects my external monitor.
Last night I tried the official/supported method by Apple for my system. Reverted back to OSX Lion and installed using Bootcamp and a Windows 7 Legacy x86 installation disc.
Basically same thing. As soon as I booted into the disc, black screen. Setup finished, installed Bootcamp drivers, black screen. Although the difference this time is that the ATI Catalyst software detects both monitors, the internal one is still black, disabled or whatever.
Perhaps GPU or firmware flashing may help? What about using another boot manager like rEFInd or something like that? I'm not knowledgeable on these but saw some people mentioning them.

Another update, I discovered today that this issue does not only affect Windows, but Linux as well. Tried to boot off a Zorin OS dvd I have in Legacy mode and behold, iMac screen turned off - external monitor turned on. So it sounds that it's something to do with the Mac's firmware (bios) or whatever? Are there any remedies/steps I can try out?
